# execute a relative path shell script from a shell script

Tags: bash

given the following:

```
# a.sh

source ./stuff/b.sh
```

and

```
# b.sh

source ./c.sh
```

folder structure

```
- a.sh
- stuff
  - b.sh
  - c.sh
```

when running `a.sh` it gives an error  `./c.sh: No such file or directory`

While I can put absolute path for c, I rather keep it relative since the scripts could run in numerous locations.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: When you're calling your script, `.` stands for the folder you're in when calling it. You can use `realpath` and `dirname` to get the absolute path to your file and create the relative path you need for your script. If you're on Mac os, try `brew install coreutils` to get `realpath` command. Hope it helps

Comment: The only script that should need to worry about its location is `a.sh`. It should export a variable like `ADIR` that contains its installation location; then everything else uses dynamic absolute paths like `$ADIR/stuff/b.sh`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A portable solution to achieve what you want consists in replacing the contents of file `b.sh` with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# (file b.sh)

srcdir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null && pwd )

source "$srcdir/c.sh"
```

As a side remark, note that it is maybe unnecessary to source the files at stake: it is especially useful if you need to export in the ambient shell session the variables defined in `c.sh`. Otherwise (if you just need to run `c.sh` as a standalone script) you may want to replace the script above with:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# (file b.sh)

srcdir=$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null && pwd )

"$srcdir/c.sh"
```

and at the same time:

- add a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) such as `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or `#!/bin/bash` at the beginning of `c.sh`
- set the executable bit of `c.sh` by doing `chmod a+x c.sh`

Comment: source "${BASH_SOURCE[0]%/*}"/c.sh is enough in b.sh

Comment: @ctac_ Indeed, `source "${BASH_SOURCE[0]%/*}"/c.sh` would be very OK if we just want to get a relative path :) But if the OP wants to get an absolute path, or in case there is some `cd` somewhere in the script `b.sh` before the line `source "${BASH_SOURCE[0]%/*}"/c.sh`), this wouldn't be enough... And the issue is that commands such as `readlink -f` to normalize the path are not POSIX... hence that cumbersome command with `pwd` which should be portable (using bash on macOS or Windows for example)

Comment: Actually I believe the command at stake is rather standard and I just saw on [Unix SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/273380) that it could be improved a bit by adding `> /dev/null` (to avoid issues with `$CDPATH`)... I'm going to refine my answer.